# Flutter: using Firebase Dynamic link, could someone tell me how to pass list of args with link and also how to receive it?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, dynamic, args

- I'm using Firebase Dynamic link in my app, and I couldn't know how to pass args with the link?
- also the way to receive it
- could someone help me to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Everything you have asked here can be found in [flutterfire docs](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/dynamic-links/usage/). Passing arguments part can be a bit confusing though, so let me explain that. The best way to think of it is the same way you pass arguments in a website, via query parameters in the url. You can add a `link` to the dynamic link, for eg

```
https://example.com/items/2
```

When you attach a listener for dynamic links in the app, you will be receiving this whole string of url in the remote message. You can then extract the required data accordingly.